# Hide extra text instead of scrolling or overflowing parent div

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a very limited space where I can display text, and I would like to hide anything extra instead of doing a line break, scrolling or overflowing parent div.

In this case my text is inside an anchor tag, so I made a small component to exemplify what I want to do here:

```js
function App () {
  return (
    <div style={{ width: 100, border: 'solid 1px black'}}>
      <a style={{ overflow: 'hidden'}} href='#'>Please hide any text that would cross the parent divs border instead of line breaking to make it longer.</a>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  mountNode
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="padding: 24px"></div>
<script>
  var mountNode = document.getElementById('container');
</script>
```

Anyway, how do I hide all that extra text in order to keep the text content of the anchor tag just one line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing `white-space: nowrap` and `display: block`.

1) `white-space: nowrap` prevents line wrapping.

2) `display: block` ensures the anchor inherits its parent's width, as opposed to its text's width.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

a {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  /* optional */
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a>Please hide any text that would cross the parent divs border instead of line breaking to make it longer.</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Move overflow hidden to the div and add whiteSpace no wrap to the link

```js
function App () {
  return (
    <div style={{overflow: 'hidden', width: 100, border: 'solid 1px black'}}>
      <a style={{ whiteSpace:'nowrap'}} href='#'>Please hide any text that would cross the parent divs border instead of line breaking to make it longer.</a>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  mountNode
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="padding: 24px"></div>
<script>
  var mountNode = document.getElementById('container');
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the css overflow property "hidden".

```html
<div style="overflow:hidden; width:100px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid black">hide any text that would cross the parent divs border instead of line breaking to make it longer</div>
```